# Variable or parameter 'XYZ' cannot be defined twice within the same template of XSL file

Tags: xslt, msxsl

This is very strange issue I see. When I execute the command:

```
msxsl.exe abc.xsl -o abc.xml
```

This runs on my machine(Windows 10 Enterprise, version 20H2) but when I run the same on other machine with same OS, it says:

```
Variable or parameter 'XYZ' cannot be defined twice within the same template
```

why is it so? code base is exactly same in both machines.

Comment: I think the error message happens when you have e.g. `<xsl:template name="foo"><xsl:param name="XYZ"/><xsl:param name="XYZ"/>..</xsl:template>`, due to the restrictions specified in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#local-variables. I can't tell why you don't get the error on one machine if the XSLT is the same as on the other machine.

Comment: I'm not sure if XSLT is same, how to check XSLT version?

Comment: You don't know whether the `abc.xsl` is the same on both machines? As for the version, the `mxsl.exe` tool uses MSXML which is an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: Oh, abc.xsl is definitely same on both machines

Comment: And does the `abc.xsl` have a template with a duplicated template parameter declaration?

Comment: Yes, it is duplicated in another template.

Comment: As I said, it will be hard to find an explanation on StackOverflow as to why you get different results if you really run the same version of a tool against the same XSLT code on the same OS version. To investigate on your own, does that `msxsl.exe` tool with `-?` or `-h` show any options as to display  which version of MSXML it uses by default? Or does it have a `-v` option to be more "verbose"?

Comment: From XSLT, to check the MSXML version you can output `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('msxml:version')"/>` (with e.g. `xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"` declared).